# Group Homomorphism binary relation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups and $r$ be a binary relation from $G$ to $H$ such that $r$ is a subgroup of $G\times H$. Then we can not say that $r$ is a group homomorphism binary relation from $G$ to $H$. Because we know that, if a mapping from $G$ to $H$ maps every subgroups of $G$ to subgroups of $H$ then the mapping may not be a group homomorphism. So I ask that what should be the definition of a group homomorphism binary relation ?

Answer (score 1):

A group homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ may be identified with a subgroup $R$ of $G \times H$ which also represents a map between the underlying sets, i.e. for all $g \in G$ there should be a unique $h \in H$ such that $(g,h) \in R$.